# Convenient type-inferring way to reassign `unique_ptr` value with new object

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

Is there a convenient way to re-assign the value of a `unique_ptr` with a *new* owned object, without re-specifying the type?

For instance:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> foo;
// .... Later, once we actually have a value to store...
foo = std::make_unique<int>(my_cool_value);
```

Of course `int` is not too much of an eyesore, but `foo::element_type` could be long or subject to change after a refactoring.

So, to use type inference, we could do:

```
foo = std::make_unique<decltype(foo)::element_type>(value);
```

...But that's pretty hideous (`foo::element_type` doesn't work because `foo` can't be used in a constant expression).

Ideally, `std::unique_ptr` would support a forwarding `emplace`-like method:

```
foo.reassign(value);
```

This would release the old value and, just like `std::vector::emplace`, construct the new owned object in-place.

....But as far as I can tell, there's nothing more concise than `make_unique<decltype(foo)::element_type>`.

**EDIT:** The most concise way to reassign the value for a type that supports `operator=` is, of course, to use `operator=`:

```
*foo = value;`
```

...But I do not want to rely on the copyability of `element_type` (for instance, I initially ran into this issue when trying to work with input-file streams).

Comment: The problem doesn't seem genuine. shorter keystrokes? or what?? Using `std::make_unique<int>` is as clear and as concise as it can be...

Comment: @WhiZTiM `int` is a trivial example here. Suppose I want to use this inside a templated function where I don't know the type of `foo::element_type`, or somewhere that I've inferred the type, or, or suppose the type is some templated monstrosity.

Comment: "`foo::element_type` doesn't work" because you can't use the scope resolution operator on a variable.

Comment: @T.C. Hm, not sure how I never realized (or had forgotten?) that. That seems like it could be a useful bit of syntax sugar.

Comment: `struct X { using type = int; }; struct Y { using type = double; } X; X::type u;` What's `decltype(u)`?

Comment: @T.C. Hm, didn't realize that types and objects could share the same fully-qualified name. But there's also potential ambiguity (not in a formal sense, since the standard arbitrates) e.g. when the type supports `operator()`; supporting `X::type` in that context (and specifying what that means, or simply leaving it unspecified--or, in a sane world, requiring a compiler error) doesn't seem like it would make things much more confusing.

Comment: The variable name hides the type name; however, `X::type` is well-formed and resolves unambiguously to `int` because name lookup before `::` ignores non-type/namespace names altogether. There's no way to make your "syntax sugar" work without either inverting the hiding rules for this case or big compatibility breaks.

Comment: @T.C. Well, it could theoretically be supported only if there is only one possibly referent for the name, and otherwise follow the standard rules, which wouldn't break compatibility because it would only work in situations that previously simply wouldn't have compiled. But I suppose I'm really just complaining about how much I dislike the language rather than making a serious feature proposal; otherwise I'd submit a paper to the committee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stash the arguments (or references thereto) into a proxy object with a templated conversion operator that deduces the target type. Then construct the new object once you have that deduced.

```
template<class... Args>
struct maker {
    template<class T>
    operator std::unique_ptr<T>() && {
        return make<T>(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
    }
    std::tuple<Args...> args;
private:  
    template<class T, size_t ... Is>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::get<Is>(std::move(args))...);
    }

};

template<class... Args>
auto maybe_make_unique_eventually(Args&&... args){
    return maker<Args&&...>{std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you. Do you mind if I add some explanatory text? (Or you can do it, but the answer will definitely be improved if it's more than just code.)

Answer (score 1):

It won't be a member function, but a free function could essentially achieve this:

```
template<typename T, typename D, typename...Args>
void TakeNew(std::unique_ptr<T,D>& up, Args&&... args)
{
  up.reset(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
  // or use parentheses for consistency with `make_unique`; see comments
}

// usage...
auto foo = std::make_unique<int>(3);
// .... Later...
TakeNew(foo, 5);
```

(I do not consider this solution ideal.)

Comment: You shouldn't use a braced_init_list there either. You don't know what kind of type `T` will be, and the caller will be expecting the arguments to call a regular constructor, not accidentally invoke an initializer list constructor. Consider what would happen if you used this on `vector<int>` and passed 3.

Comment: @GManNickG Why, for exception safety? `make_unique` wouldn't provide any additional protection in this case, and would force the use of the standard deleter.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I realize that brace-initialization is inconsistent, and I suppose using parentheses would be more consistent with `make_unique` and other `std` functions. I don't think the choice of one or the other is obviously more correct, though; what if I *want* access to an initializer list constructor? (E.g. `TakeNew(my_arraylike_object, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6....)`.)

Comment: @KyleStrand: `TakeNew(my_arraylike_object, std::initializer_list<int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...))` It's a bit wordy, but it gives everyone (except people who need to initialize aggregates) something that they can use. And the aggregate issue is an issue for *any* `emplace`-style function. All `emplace`-style functions in the standard library use constructor syntax. It's not a good idea to go against the standard convention in this way.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Ah, didn't see the deleter. Fair enough, then.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <memory>


// a class with a long and unweildy name
namespace mary {
  namespace poppins {
    struct supercalafragalisticexpialadocious
    {
    };
  }
}


int main()
{
  // what we don't want to have to do:

  auto a = std::make_unique<mary::poppins::supercalafragalisticexpialadocious>();

  // so alias the typename

  using atrocious = mary::poppins::supercalafragalisticexpialadocious;

  // same type with a shorter name
  a = std::make_unique<atrocious>();
}
```

Comment: Brevity is not the only advantage of type-inference.

Answer (score 0):

As you have unique ownership, unless the type is not copyable, you may simply do

```
*foo = value;
```

Comment: The owned object won't be a new object, though, and I *do* want to handle non-copyable types (this issue arose when I was trying to assign to `unique_ptr<ifstream>` and forgot the `f` in `ifstream`).

Comment: You're right, though, that this is probably often (usually?) the right technique for reassigning the *value* of an owned object.

Comment: For `ifstream`, you may `close()` then `open(..)` it. `std::swap` might also be an alternative for some type.